# Elixirのテスト監視にビューを加えたい

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.1のElixirでファイルの監視とテストを実施しています。appとtestsディレクトリ以下のファイルを変更した時には自動でPHPUnitが動きます。

resources/viewsディレクトリ以下のファイルも監視対象に加えたいのですが、どの様にしたら出来るでしょうか？

[設定ファイル]

```
// gulpfile.js

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.phpUnit();
});
```

[テスト監視の実行]

```
$ gulp tdd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.phpUnit([
        "tests/**/*Test.php",
        "resources/views/**/*.php"
    ]);
});
```

でいかがでしょうか。

Comment: resourcesの方のパス指定ですが、"resources/views/**/*.php"の誤りではないでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。修正しました。